# ES File Explorer unable to access `/storage/emulated/legacy` which it did earlier

Tags: file-permissions, es-file-explorer

I suddenly have a weird problem with the Android phone running version Android 4.2.2. I never rooted the phone but suddenly the app ES File Explorer is not able to access `/storage/emulated/legacy` which it did earlier. This contains my photos, videos and the likes. Even some of the apps are beginning to crash when I try to open them. I cannot even connect to Wi-Fi. I can only call and read/send SMS.

I tried using ADB to access the file system. See the result of `ls -l` on `/storage/emulated/legacy`,

```
shell@G20:/storage/emulated $ ls -l
ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-09-01 03:41 0 -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-09-01 03:41 legacy -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0
```

And if I follow the `/mnt/shell/emulated/0` symlink, the following is the actual permission,

```
shell@G20:/mnt/shell/emulated $ ls -l
ls -l
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2015-09-01 19:53 0
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2037-12-31 05:31 legacy
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2015-08-20 12:45 obb
```

I'm wondering how might have this happened. I never rooted my phone and is still under warranty so, I cannot root. Hence, solution without rooting will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think those permissions are causing the issue since they are same in my Lollipop. Is factory reset not an option for you? What are the results with other file explorer apps?

Comment: Yeah using ADB I can access the files but not using my phone. Is there any way I could check what user is being used to access the underlying OS files from my phone? I'm really frustrated now.

Comment: I have important smss and without root I cannot back them up I suppose to my PC and because I cannot the os from the phone I cannot even save them using copy paste or whatever.

Comment: With other file explorer is the same. I also have FileExplorer or something.

Comment: [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) can backup and restore your SMS without root, so as [SMS Backup and Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en). Also, if you want to backup SMS but are not concerned for restoring them then you can take screenshot of them on Android or on PC (see [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)).

Comment: I tried SMS Backup and Restore but when I try to configure the write location, I cannot use any because the phone cannot write to any one. And when I tried to take screenshot then the save fails with an error 'operation failed'. Whatever, be the case, let me try with AirDriod if I can take a screenshot directly using the PC and store in in the PC filesystem itself. I'll get back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems I can take screenshot with ADB. Cool! I'll try a factory reset.

Comment: @firelord adb screenshot is a great idea. Also try and access pictures, videos, and such check with ES these locations. Because there's more than one entrance to folders though it's not the real path. /system/mnt/sdcard or /system/sdcard or /system/sdcard0 (it's different folder than just 0) One other thing try a different  file Explorer such as FX file explorer. Pull logs to find out what's going on with your device.

Comment: @BoLawson: Where do you find the logs in the file system? Forgive my ignorance. I'm new to Android and ADB.

Comment: Using a PC open a prompt then.   adb logcat *:W *:S > %userprofile%\desktop\logcat.txt  if using an terminal emulator  from within device then this will put text on sdcard.  adb logcat > /sdcard/logcat.txt

Comment: @BoLawson: I'll get back to you. Thanks a lot!